# How to assign multiple values to an array?

Tags: c++

I can declare and initialize an array like this:

```cpp
int dest_linesize[4] = {  4 , 0 , 0 , 0 };
```

I can always assign values to the individual members of the array by:

```cpp
dest_linesize[0] = 5;
```

But can I assign multiple values with something like this?

```cpp
dest_linesize = {  4 , 3 , 1 , 0 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C-style array? No, they are not reassignable.

With C++ [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)? Sure

```
#include <array>
int main()
{
    std::array<int, 4> dest_linesize = {4 , 0 , 0 , 0 };
    dest_linesize[0] = 5;
    for(int n:dest_linesize) {
        std::cout << n << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    dest_linesize = {  4 , 3 , 1 , 0 };
    for(int n:dest_linesize) {
        std::cout << n << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: if i have to pass a c style array to a function how can i pass the std::array ?

Comment: @shomit If you can't change that function, [`dest_linesize.data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data) will extract the underlying array.

Answer (score 2):

> can i do something like this instead where i can assign multiple values.
>
> ```
> dest_linesize = {  4 , 3 , 1 , 0 };
> ```

No, you cannot. Arrays are not assignable.

One solution is to wrap the array inside a class. Classes are assignable. There is a template for such wrapper in the standard library. It is called `std::array`. Example:

```
std::array dest_linesize = {  4 , 0 , 0 , 0 };
dest_linesize = {  4 , 3 , 1 , 0 }
```